# Find In String - Count Position

Tags: php, string, loops, search

I'm currently writing a small piece of code to search through a string to find a given word.

The following is how I'm doing it:

```
function search($string) {
    if (strpos($string,'cat') !== false) {
        echo 'Found it';
        echo $string;
    } else {

    }
}
```

So far, the above successfully searches the string and if it finds the given word it will also echo out the part of the string it is contained in. As a note, the $string is the output of a FOR loop.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
        $href = $hrefs->item($i);
        $string = $href->textContent;

            search($string);

    }
```

To show you what the output of the FOR loop looks:

1. website.com
2. cat.com
3. website.com
4. website.com
5. website.com

So my code checks through that output, finds the URL containing the word cat and gives the success.

However, what I also want to do it count what position of the string cat is found in. So if it is found in the second URL in the string, I also want to be able to output "Position 2".

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mean the position in the list, its position $i+1.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $string = $href->textContent;

        if search($string) echo 'Position is ' . $i+1;

}

function search($string) {
    if (strpos($string,'cat') !== false) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {....
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function search($string) {
    if (strpos($string,'cat') !== false) {
        echo 'Found it on postition ';
        echo strpos($string,'cat')."</br>";
        echo $string;
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with doing it like this is that it ouputs what letter position of the string it's in: e.g: 18th letter.

Comment: It would be better if you cache the return value from `strpos($string,'cat')`.